# Error in OptaPlanner when multithreading (External object cannot be looked up)

Tags: optaplanner

I have developped an optimization module using OptaPlanner but have encountered an error when multithreading. Note that the module works when multithreading is disabled. I tried several OptaPlanner versions (8.4, 8.1, 7.51) and different JDKs (16 and 14).

I used a simple solver configuration file
[image: Sover config]

**

My planning entity is also straghtforward :

**

```
@PlanningSolution public class SuccessPromotion  {
    
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public ArrayList<RCT> rcts;
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public ArrayList<RCT_Planning> rcts_promos;
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "availablePromotion")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<int[]> promotions;
    @PlanningScore
    public HardSoftScore score;
    @PlanningId
    public String name; //Constructors //Getter & Setter }
```

**
The error I get is as follows :
**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move
> thread with moveThreadIndex (3) has thrown an exception. Relayed here
> in the parent thread.     at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:188)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:159)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:71)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:189)
> at test.RealSolver.main(RealSolver.java:140) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The externalObject ([I@5ce1e52a)
> cannot be looked up. Some functionality, such as multithreaded
> solving, requires this ability. Maybe add an @PlanningId annotation on
> an identifier property of the class (class [I). Or otherwise, maybe
> change the @PlanningSolution annotation's LookUpStrategyType (not
> recommended).     at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.NoneLookUpStrategy.lookUpWorkingObject(NoneLookUpStrategy.java:44)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.lookUpWorkingObject(LookUpManager.java:76)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(AbstractScoreDirector.java:512)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:83)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:31)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:140)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is

```
The externalObject ([I@5ce1e52a) cannot be looked up. Some functionality, such as multithreaded solving, requires this ability. Maybe add an @PlanningId annotation on an identifier property of the class (class [I).
```

That `class[I` talks about your planning value class (`int[]`), not your planning entity class (`ArrayList<RCT_Planning>`).

The planning value class `int[]` is neither immutable, nor has a `@PlanningId`, so it can't rebase it easily to another thread (although in theory it could copy it, it doesn't do so at the moment). The error message could be better.

Workaround: wrap `int[]` in a planning value class.

Comment: For future readers, I created a class where I wrapped the promotions var of type int[] as suggested. The promotions variable holds the possible values of the PlanningEntity. I added a planningid to the class.